# Is it possible for Vue Web Components to have listeners or interact some other way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-component

I am trying to develop multiple Vue.js components written as .vue single file components. The requirements is that such components need to be embedded by front-end designers directly into HTML using  element.

Since i cannot achieve this with default compilation method provided by webpack, i figured out it could be done by compiling (more correctly, transpiling) as web components.

Is it possible to use Vue Web Components with listeners as you would with regular Vue Components?

```
<some-web-component @some-event="someFunction()"></some-web-component>
```

I couldn't find any examples of this, all which i found had only a simple component with some props, displaying a message. Is this even possible?

If not, is there some other way to achieve communication between Web Components?

Similarly asked here:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-vue-single-page-components-directly-in-html/66384

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering the same, I've found the solution to be using Vuex store.

Comment: How do you interact with the Vuex store? Do you expose Vuex Store in some way?